# Rewrite Url with Get and hide extension

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a website with remove .php extension. My .htaccess

```
Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://sampsv.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC, L]
```

And I have the URL like this:

> https://myweb.com/panel/server?id=1234

How can I convert it to:

> https://myweb.com/panel/server/1234

I'm trying, but it show 404 error.

**UPDATE**

I'm used this Code :

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/([\d]+)$ server.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But my Website show Error Message, can't found any data.

My Code:

```
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
  echo 'Ok';
}
else
{
  echo 'Can't Found any Data';
}
```

Comment: Try this:
RedirectMatch 301 https://myweb.com/panel/server?id=1234(.*) https://myweb.com/panel/server/1234/$1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rule i am assuming server is a php file,

```
Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://sampsv.com/$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\d]+)$ server.php?id=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks you so much , i did it.